# How to test code throws a `cv2.error` in OpenCV

Tags: python, unit-testing, opencv, error-handling

I am using OpenCV for a project (version 3.2.0) and I have a part of my code that calls [`cv2.grabCut`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga909c1dda50efcbeaa3ce126be862b37f) on an image, as in

```
import cv2    

cv2.grabCut(image,
            mask,
            None,
            bgd_model,
            fgd_model,
            5,
            cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
```

which fails in the case of images which are somehow too small for it to compute anything. In these cases, the error thrown by OpenCV is

```
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv3-20170714-64983-13zymq9/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp:379: error: (-215) !bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty() in function initGMMs
```

Now, I need to write a unit test that checks this really happens and I'm using [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) for it. How would I go about catching this error? `assertRaises` isn't looking promising for the job.

Comment: Try capturing stderr by redirecting it (e.g. http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/09/27/Capturing-stderr-and-exceptions-from-python-in-org-mode/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that is extracted from http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/09/27/Capturing-stderr-and-exceptions-from-python-in-org-mode/

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    oe = sys.stderr
    re = sys.stderr = StringIO()

    print >>sys.stderr, '###test###'
    value = re.getvalue()
    if "###test###" in value:
        sys.stderr = oe
        raise Exception("ERROR")
```

We redirect the stderr (but we save a reference to the original one beforehand). Then when we need to test its value we test it and restore strerr back once we are done (if we don't, then exception messages will be redirected and won't appear on the terminal).